# How to sync the data with web server once device came into network?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

In my app  which is  data collection app i need offline support. Let's say when i am gathering user's data there is no connection on device but once the device comes in network the whole data should automatically goes to the server.
How should i implement this kind of functionality.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, but I assume you're wondering HOW to persist data and not how to automatically send it to the server.

If the data is very simple, [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html) may suffice.

If you need a bit more complicated data structures, you can use [archives](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).

If you need to store complex object graphs you need to use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

There's a pretty good guide explaining all of these [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891031/ios-offline-data-storage-tutorial).